# on click event for input type date placeholder shifts

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, placeholder

I have a input type which by default is `text` but on Its click event, I make it as `date`.

But when I trigger the click event date placeholder shifts at the top, i.e. CSS breaks, for both Android and iOS.

What is the reason behind this? Please suggest

Comment: please give the code you worked?

Comment: "*…on Its click event, I make it as date*". That does not seem like a good idea.